# Best Method for Continuous Target

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, sas, continuous-data

- I am trying to build a model where my target is continuous with a
  right-skewed distribution. I am interested to know what are possible
  models I can try apart from linear regression.
- I have around 200  Predictors(mostly numeric and few categorical) and
  45,000 records.
- Target Ranges from 10-100 (80% sample less has target value than 50).
  My goal is to predict either '*exact value*' or *in the correct band(10-15, 15-20,20-25..95-100).*

Thank you

Comment: All of the supervised learning regression methods are viable: regularized regression, random forest, support vector regression, neural networks. However, what is your goal in fitting the regression? That may help constrain the problem.

Comment: Apart from indicating the response is continuous and you have a dataset of moderate size, you haven't supplied any information that would distinguish any particular method as more or less appropriate.